# HTTPS over IPv6 only working inside my LAN (HTTP is fine)

Tags: ssl, https, ipv6

I'm trying to expose a web server to the internet.

Sockets are apparently ok:

```
$ ss -tupan -6 state listening | grep node
tcp    0      128            *:7443                       *:*                   users:(("node-default",pid=28327,fd=26))
tcp    0      128            *:7777                       *:*                   users:(("node-default",pid=28327,fd=25))
```

I've exposed ports 7777 and 7443 on my router's firewall and my server's firewalld.

```
$ firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=home
home (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wlan0
  sources: 
  services: ssh mdns samba-client dhcpv6-client samba openvpn
  ports: 7777/tcp 7443/tcp
  protocols: ipv6-icmp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

As far as I can tell, HTTP is working fine:

http://[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]:7777/]

Unfortunately, so far https is only accessible from inside my LAN:

https://[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]:7443

Any idea on what the problem may be / how to further troubleshoot it?

PS: I'm using a self signed certificate for now.

---

#### Update 1: iptables rules

```
$ ip6tables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
14796   14M ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 1938  155K ACCEPT     all      lo     *       ::/0                 ::/0                
  861 98439 INPUT_direct  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
  861 98439 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
  861 98439 INPUT_ZONES  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "STATE_INVALID_DROP: "
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
   20  2013 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "FINAL_REJECT: "
   20  2013 REJECT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      lo     *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "STATE_INVALID_DROP: "
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "FINAL_REJECT: "
    0     0 REJECT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 15085 packets, 2863K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
15681 3011K OUTPUT_direct  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_home  all      wlan0  *       ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_public  all      +      *       ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_home  all      *      wlan0   ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_public  all      *      +       ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_home (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_home_log  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FWDI_home_deny  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FWDI_home_allow  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain FWDI_home_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_home_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_home_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_home (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_home_log  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FWDO_home_deny  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FWDO_home_allow  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain FWDO_home_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_home_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_home_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  753 87315 IN_home    all      wlan0  *       ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 
   34  3461 IN_public  all      +      *       ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_home (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  827 94978 IN_home_log  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
  827 94978 IN_home_deny  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
  827 94978 IN_home_allow  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
  719 80600 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain IN_home_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
   77 11842 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ff02::fb             udp dpt:5353 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:137 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:138 ctstate NEW
    1   136 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 fe80::/64            udp dpt:546 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:137 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:138 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:139 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:445 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpts:1714:1764 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpts:1714:1764 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:1194 ctstate NEW
   16  1280 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:7777 ctstate NEW
   14  1120 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:7443 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_home_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_home_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   34  3461 IN_public_log  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
   34  3461 IN_public_deny  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
   34  3461 IN_public_allow  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
   14  1448 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 fe80::/64            udp dpt:546 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

#### Update 2 - Router Rules:

[image: Router Rules]

Router is an Asus DSL-AC68U

Comment: Maybe dump the raw ip6tables -nvL rules and see what is going on?

Comment: @Zoredache, updated with ip6tables logs. Lots of things going on due to firewalld. I can see ports 7443 and 7777 open (`IN_home_allow`). However, I'm not very familiar with IPv6 specific rules.

Comment: Well your rules look like they are probably good.  Might need to fire up tcpdump/wireshark and capture on port 7443.

Comment: @Zoredache, with tcpdump port 7777 gives me traffic, port 7443 gives me nothing. Maybe the problem is the router?

Comment: Maybe, or something else about your network configuration.  Perhaps try capturing from the perspective of your client or something.  Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to access this url from my network:

https://[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]:7443/

I get a certificate warning error in Firefox, issued to selfcert.local, SHA-1 fingerprint `52:52:AB:48:BA:75:74:85:8E:F4:5A:46:46:E6:47:CB:CE:6A:D4:36`.

It may be something else to do with your configuration, such as possibly the Asuswrt firmware or another device is not routing its own IPv6 network correctly. From my IPv6 network to yours, the connection works and I receive your self-signed certificate.

Comment: Oopss... You are totally right. Since http was working I never thought that the problem would be the client. However, [IPv6 Proxy](http://www.ipv6proxy.net) works and displays "Hello World!". After reading your answer I've tried Firefox and couldn't even get the http version. Turns out that Chrome Data Saver was proxying http traffic. Mistery solved :). –